# Is there any way to iterate over list inside list in django template?

Tags: python-3.x, django, list, django-templates, django-2.2

I have a list a = [[1000,3000], [4000-5000]], i would like to show it has
1000-3000
4000-5000 in template. But i'm getting only the first object.
What i tried is,

products.html

```
{% for i in price_group %}

    <label>
        <input class="uk-radio" type="radio" onchange="$('#form').submit();" name="price" value="{{ i.0.0 }};{{ i.0.1 }};price;first" checked>
                                            {{ i.0.0 }} - {{ i.0.1 }}
    </label>
       
      {{ price_group.pop.i }}
{% endfor %}
```

I used pop functionality to remove current from the list and take the next one, but it's not working as expected.
it is showing only the first element in the list. Please correct me if I am wrong. What I want is it has a price range like.
1000-3000
4000-5000..like wise. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing only first element of the list, you need to update your code to access all the elements like this:

```
{% for i,j in price_group %} 
<label> <input class="uk-radio" type="radio" onchange="$('#form').submit();" name="price" value="{{ i }};{{ j }};price;first" checked> 
{{ i }} - {{ j }} 
</label> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but if I put like the way you said, I'm getting something like this 
[121.0, 1233.0] - [2345.0, 14000.0]. but what I want it as given below
121.0 - 1233,
2345 - 14000

Comment: Can you post the data structure of price_group?

Comment: price_group is list only. Which looks like this [[1000,3000][3000,4000][5000,6000]..] likewise. I want to show its price range in html.. 1000-3000, 3000-4000 like wise.

Comment: You have to unpack the values in each sublist in order to iterate over list of list.I've updated the code, please try it once.

Comment: hi thanks for the update. now its coming as [121.0, 1233.0] - [2345.0, 14000.0]. What i wanted is 121.0 - 1233.0 like wise. need to access the inner list values. It is price range actually. need another loop?

Comment: I think,then your data structure of price_group is not list of list, it should be list of list of list(i.e 2 nested list in a list). Please check this once and post the structure of price_group again.

Comment: hi..this is how it looks like 
ipdb> price_group                                                                                                        
[[121.0, 1233.0], [2345.0, 14000.0]]
ipdb> type(price_group)                                                                                                  
<class 'list'>

Comment: The code that I've posted is working fine for printing data in desired format i.e 121.0-1233.0,2345.0-14000.0.Maybe some other bug is there in your codebase.Please check again.